# If $\{x : g(x) \le y_0 \}$ is convex, closed for all $y_0$, is $\{(x,y) : g(x) \le y\}$ closed?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

> Let $g(x): \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$. Suppose that for all $y_0 \in \Bbb R$, the set $\{x \in\Bbb R^{n} : x \in X ,g(x) \le y_0\}$ is closed and convex, where $X$ is a non-empty subset of $\Bbb R^n$. Is it true that the set $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^{n+1}:x\in X,g(x) \le y\}$ is closed?

My thoughts: $$\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^{n+1}:x\in X,g(x) \le y\} = \bigcup_{y_0 \in \Bbb R} \{x\in\Bbb R^{n}:x\in X,g(x) \le y_0\} \times \{y_0\}.$$ However, an infinite union of closed sets is not guaranteed to be closed. I think we should use the convexity, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: It is closed for every  $y_0$. In particular, taking $y_0=y$....

Comment: I think I understand what you meant to write. Can you check that my edit doesn't change the question?

Comment: Also, what is $X$?

Comment: Thanks. The edit is OK. $X$ is any non-empty set in $\Bbb R^n$. This problem is related to optimization, so $X$ can be understood as a constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that $X$ is closed.

Note that the function $g$ is lower semi continuous (lsc.).

Hence if $(x_n,y_n) \to (x,y)$ with $x_n \in X$ and and $g(x_n) \le y_n$, then
$g(x) \le \liminf_n g(x_n) \le \liminf_n y_n = y$, hence
$(x,y)$ is in the epigraph.

**Addendum**:

The assumption that $X$ is closed is not strictly necessary, but
avoids a minor technicality.

If we define $\hat{g}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ by $\hat{g}(x) = g(x) + \delta(x| X)$, where $\delta$ is Rockafellar's
indicator function (zero on $X$, $+\infty$ elsewhere) then we see
that the level sets $L_\alpha = \{x | \hat{g}(x) \le \alpha \}$
are closed (by assumption) for any real $\alpha$, hence $\hat{g}$
is lsc. It follows from the same argument as above that the epigraph of
$\hat{g}$ is closed.

(Note that for real $\alpha$, $\hat{g}(x) \le \alpha$ **iff** $x \in X$ and $g(x) \le \alpha$.)

This holds if $\mathbb{R}^n$ is replaced by a Banach space.